# build jar with specific external dependencies

Tags: java, build, jar

To interface with another java application, I've built a jar with my code.

Everything works fine when i start adding dependencies (other jars) that seem to conflict with the other application.

Is there anyway i can use my dependencies without affecting the other application?

At the moment I'm dropping my jar in the lib folder of the other application, and then my dependencies on the same folder. I'm looking for something like jar in lib folder and my dependencies on Mylibs folder in the lib folder.

Comment: you can put your libs wherever you want them to be, a long as java can find them.  Research `java classpath` to learn how to do this.  Alternatively, you can package your jar such that the other libraries are inside it (with this option, be careful you don't intrude on any licenses).

Comment: @RussellUhl the thing is, the other application behavior is being affected by the dependencies I'm dropping in the lib folder. Seems we share some dependencies of different versions.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear.  Option 1: indeed, move your libs to a different folder where the "other application" can't find them.  Then point your application to the new directory using the classpath .  Option 2: embed your libraries in your jar so that the "other application" is completely unaware of their existence.

Comment: perhaps my question wasn't clear, i was asking for some guidance in that process, should my ant script just add to the manifest the jars from another folder? Will this stop with the conflicts?

Comment: ahhhhhh ok.  Well if you're using ant files I can't help you.  Never could get those suckers to work.  Having said that, I'd google something like "java ant set classpath".  For option A, your classpath would look something like `.:./MyLibs/*.jar`  I believe this information is sent to the `.Classpath` file that gets created inside your jar.